# how to get the constant inside a php class without using reflection

Tags: php

Is that possible to get the constant that is defined inside a class without using the reflection class?

I want something like this:

```
<?php 

class Test {
    const URL = 'https://www.example.com';

    public function get($constant)
    {
        return $constant;
    }
}

$test = new Test();

$test->get('URL');
```

I want the output to be the value of the `URL`, which is 'https://www.example.com'. However, right now it just return the actual word 'URL'.

Comment: As simple as `Test::URL`, as shown in the [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way:

```
class Test {
    const URL = 'https://www.example.com';

    public function get($constant)
    {
          return constant('Test::'.$constant);
    }
}

$test = new Test();

echo $test->get('URL');
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I'm looking for. By the way, can I change the `'Test::'.$constant` to `'self::'.$constant`?

Answer (score 0):

Of course it does, you are simply returning the Input back to the user. If you want to access a constant via its name do the following:

```
<?php 
class Test {
    const URL = 'https://www.example.com';
}

echo Test::URL;
```

Comment: Since I'm writing this code in a MVC project, I'd like to do something like `$this->load->model('test); $this->test->get('URL');`. How do I apply it?

Comment: Then have a look at @mehulmpts answer, his approach is probably what you are looking for.